# only allowing numbers upto certain length in material ui

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

We need user to enter only numbers and it should have a maximum length of say 3.
How can we accomplish this in material ui ?

```
<TextField
  id="score"
  label="score"
  className={classes.textField}
  name="totalScore"
  margin="normal"
  defaultValue={score}
/>
```

We want only numeric values here

Comment: try this: define `type='number'` and `inputProps={{ maxLength: 3 }}`

Comment: @MayankShukla the maxlength doesn't seem to be working .

Comment: try this: instead of `inputProps`, use maxLength directly like `maxLength={3}`

Answer (score 7):

Try this...

```
<TextField
  id="score"
  label="score"
  name="totalScore"
  style={style.filedStyle}
  inputProps={{ min: 3, max: 3}}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is the way it works, you have input type as `number`. so, you can apply max attribute but it will validate not limit the input numbers, Checkout this [thread](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/5309).

The workaround is to apply oninput and count the length. like this

```
 onInput={(e)=>{ 
        e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,3)
```

So your textinput would look like

```
<TextField type="number"
    className="text-field-amount"
    onInput={(e)=>{ 
        e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,2)
    }}
    min={0}
/>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ynj9jz)

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextField
  id="score"
  label="score"
  className={classes.textField}
  name="totalScore"
  margin="normal"
  defaultValue={score}
/>
```

you can do this with Jquery

```
$('#score').keypress(function(e){
    var code = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if($('#' + e.target.id).val().length > 2)
        e.preventDefault();
    if (code > 31 && (code < 48 || code > 57)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey.The max length property doesn't seem to be working .

Comment: and what about numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Use controlled input, and update state only if the input is number.

ex: 
state will be like this

```
this.state={
    score: 0
}
```

create a function to handle change in text field.

```
handleChange(e){
    //update state here with value from TextField.
}
```

and your textfield will look like this.

```
<TextField
  id="score"
  label="score"
  className={classes.textField}
  name="totalScore"
  margin="normal"
  value={this.state.score}
  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
             <TextField
              id="number"
              placeholder="Enter Number"
              type="number"
              value={state.count}
              onChange={(event) => {
                const regex = /^([0-9]){minLength,maxLength}$/;
                if (event.target.value === '' || regex.test(event.target.value)) {
                  setState({ ...state, count: event.target.value });
                }
              }}
              variant="outlined" />
```

Answer (score 0):

number + length restriction

```
<TextField
   value={phone}
   onChange={event => setPhone(event.target.value)}
   variant="outlined"
   placeholder={'Phone number'}
   type={'number'}
   onInput={(e)=>{e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value)).toString().slice(0,10)}}
   min={0} 
/>
```

Comment: Please try to give proper explanation of the answer.